# How to iterate Outlook Inbox by Date? - Outlook OLE Automation

Tags: ruby, automation, outlook, ole, win32ole

I'd like to iterate Outlook Inbox and I'm with Ruby.

I've found some useful info [here](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2007/08/automating-outlook-with-ruby-inbox.html), but the order of message in Inbox is not ordered by RecevedTime(Property for Item OLE object). GetLast method may find the latest message but GetPrevious method does not work as I expected.

```
require 'win32ole'

outlook = WIN32OLE.new('Outlook.Application')
mapi    = outlook.GetNameSpace('MAPI')
inbox   = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6)

inbox.Items.GetLast # return the latest message, maybe
inbox.Items.GetPrevious # return nil object and then, what's this method for?
inbox.Items.Sort('ReceivedTime')    # is this right usage? if so, what's next?
```

How can I iterate messages in Inbox from the latest to the oldest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'win32ole'

ol = WIN32OLE.new('Outlook.Application')
class OC; end
WIN32OLE.const_load(ol, OC)

mapi = ol.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
inbox = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(OC::OlFolderInbox)
items = inbox.items
items.sort('ReceivedTime', OC::OlAscending)

items.getfirst
items.getnext

items.getlast
items.getprevious
```